# Music player written in Python using PyQt

Tags: python, audio, qt

Some days ago, in the middle of a flight, in one hour or so, I've written this basic music player using Python3 and PyQt4.

I needed some easy to use music player, so I decided to write this piece of code that just works.

This little guy is called Frederic. It uses, besides PyQt for the GUI, a library called mutagen to work with tags in the music files.

This is my first time with Code Review, so I decided to publish this little piece of code to try it.

Any criticism, suggestion and opinion is welcome. Thanks!

frederic.py:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.phonon import Phonon
from mutagen.id3 import ID3

class Frederic(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)

        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.setWindowTitle("Frederic Music Player")
        self.move(400, 200)

        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.status = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.play = QtGui.QPushButton("Play")
        self.pause = QtGui.QPushButton("Pause")
        self.stop = QtGui.QPushButton("Stop")
        self.siguiente = QtGui.QPushButton("Siguiente")
        self.anterior = QtGui.QPushButton("Anterior")
        self.listWidget = QtGui.QListWidget(self)

        self.agregar = QtGui.QPushButton("Agregar")
        self.eliminar = QtGui.QPushButton("Eliminar")
        self.artist = None
        self.song = None

        # Phonon settings

        self.player = Phonon.createPlayer(Phonon.MusicCategory)
        self.player.setTickInterval(100)
        self.player.tick.connect(self.ticking)
        self.spin = Phonon.SeekSlider(self.player, self)

        # Implementing the layout

        vbox.addWidget(self.label)
        vbox.addWidget(self.status)

        hbox0 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)

        hbox0.addWidget(self.play)
        hbox0.addWidget(self.pause)
        hbox0.addWidget(self.stop)
        hbox0.addWidget(self.anterior)
        hbox0.addWidget(self.siguiente)

        vbox.addLayout(hbox0)

        vbox.addWidget(self.listWidget)

        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)

        hbox.addWidget(self.agregar)
        hbox.addWidget(self.eliminar)

        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        vbox.addWidget(self.spin)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.play.clicked.connect(self.funcPlay)
        self.agregar.clicked.connect(self.funcAgregar)
        self.eliminar.clicked.connect(self.funcEliminar)
        self.pause.clicked.connect(lambda: self.player.pause())
        self.stop.clicked.connect(lambda: self.player.stop())
        self.player.aboutToFinish.connect(self.nextSongQueued)
        self.siguiente.clicked.connect(self.nextSong)
        self.anterior.clicked.connect(self.previousSong)

        self.file_name = None
        self.data = None
        self.songs = {}
        self.SongPlaying = None
        self.SongQueued = None

    def funcPlay(self):
        self.label.setText(self.listWidget.currentItem().text())
        CurrentSong = (self.listWidget.currentItem().text())
        self.SongPlaying = CurrentSong
        SongToPlay = self.songs[CurrentSong]
        self.player.setCurrentSource(Phonon.MediaSource(SongToPlay))
        self.player.play()

    def funcPause(self):
        self.player.pause()

    def ticking(self, time):
        displayTime = QtCore.QTime(0, (time / 60000) % 60, (time / 1000) % 60)
        self.status.setText(displayTime.toString('mm:ss'))

    def funcAgregar(self):
        self.file_name = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, "Open Data File", "", "MP3 (*.mp3)")

        id3 = ID3(self.file_name)

        try:
            self.data = self.artist = id3['TPE1'].text[0] + " - " + id3["TIT2"].text[0]
            self.songs[self.data] = self.file_name
            self.listWidget.addItem(self.data)
        except:
            self.data
            self.songs[self.file_name] = self.file_name
            self.listWidget.addItem(self.data)
            d = QtGui.QMessageBox()
            d.setWindowTitle('Error!')
            d.setText("El archivo que ha elegido no funciona. Seleccione otro archivo por favor.")
            d.exec_()

    def funcEliminar(self):
        self.listWidget.takeItem(self.ui.listWidget.currentRow())

    def nextSongQueued(self):
        next = self.listWidget.currentRow() + 1
        nextSong = self.listWidget.item(next).text()
        self.SongQueued = nextSong
        SongToPlay = self.songs[nextSong]
        self.player.enqueue(Phonon.MediaSource(SongToPlay))
        self.label.setText(self.SongQueued)
        self.SongPlaying = self.SongQueued

    def nextSong(self):
        next = self.listWidget.currentRow() + 1
        nextSong = self.listWidget.item(next).text()
        self.SongQueued = nextSong
        SongToPlay = self.songs[nextSong]
        self.label.setText(self.SongQueued)
        self.SongPlaying = self.SongQueued
        self.player.setCurrentSource(Phonon.MediaSource(SongToPlay))
        self.player.play()
        self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(next)

    def previousSong(self):
        next = self.listWidget.currentRow() - 1
        nextSong = self.listWidget.item(next).text()
        self.SongQueued = nextSong
        SongToPlay = self.songs[nextSong]
        self.label.setText(self.SongQueued)
        self.SongPlaying = self.SongQueued
        self.player.setCurrentSource(Phonon.MediaSource(SongToPlay))
        self.player.play()
        self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(next)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = Frederic()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4):

It can be a pleasure to whip something up in an hour on the plane. This code could be improved by using pylint.

The most obvious improvements appear to be

- minimize and structure the instance variables
- refactor code to remove repetition
- corner case testing
- make styling standard and consistent

There are so many unstructured instant variables that it obscures the structure, some errors and the
fact that many are not needed.

As a small example, of the following variables:

```
self.file_name = None
self.data = None
self.songs = {}
self.SongPlaying = None
self.SongQueued = None
```

only `self.songs` is actually used as anything but a local variable.  Similarly,
none of the buttons need to be instance variables.  In the UI only three widgets
are actually referenced outside of setup.

Where possible prefer self-documenting code.  The `songs` variable might better
be called `filename_by_track_label`.

There is a good amount of code repetition.  For example, `funcPlay`, `nextSong`
and `previousSong` all contain duplicated code. It could be factored out into
something such as

```
def play_song(self, song_index):
    """Play song at :song_index: in UI list"""
    next_track_label = self.ui.update_label_by_index(song_index)
    next_filename = self.filenames_by_track_label[next_track_label]
    self.player.setCurrentSource(Phonon.MediaSource(next_filename))
    self.player.play()
    self.ui.songs_list_widget.setCurrentRow(song_index)
```

You could further remove code duplication in the UI construction by use of a helper,
for example

```
def help_add(container, widget_list):
    for widget in widget_list:
        container.addWidget(widget)

hbox0 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
help_add(hbox0, (play_btn, pause_btn, stop_btn, anterior_btn, siguiente_btn))

hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
help_add(hbox, (agregar_btn, eliminar_btn))

vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
help_add(vbox, (self.label, self.status, hbox0, self.songs_list_widget, hbox, spin))
```

There are a number of bugs lingering in the code

- all next and previous track computations will overflow.  Computation should be
  modulus number of tracks

  ```
  song_index = (self.ui.current_song_number() + 1) % self.ui.song_count()
  ```
- track label formation catches exceptions but (a) uses a bare `except`, (b)
  largely repeats the try block in the exception handler, (c) inserts the malformed
  label and (d) includes a dangling variable name.  Perhaps something like this:

  ```
  try:
      id3 = ID3(file_name)
      data = id3['TPE1'].text[0] + " - " + id3["TIT2"].text[0]
      self.filenames_by_track_label[data] = file_name
      self.ui.listWidget.addItem(data)
  except (IOError, LookupError):
      self.ui.show_error("El archivo que ha elegido no funciona. Seleccione otro archivo por favor.")
  ```

You might consider separating the UI from the controller to provide some structure.
I have shown some elements of that in my examples with `self.ui`

Of course in an hour you might not apply completely consistent styling but pylint
can help you be disciplined.  Applying its recommendations would further improve the code.